# Activities Animation overide problem

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

currently I"m using [public void overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, int exitAnim)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) to acheive this goal. I've discovered that I dont have to rely on animations created instead I can use some android animations as below.

```
fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(BerlinWallActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
fadeout =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(BerlinWallActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

but my problem is overidePendingTransition doesn't take Animation as parameters:( it fails pathetically. How can I reuse fadein, fadeout animation variables to acheive the same goal??

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) takes two resource IDs as parameters, not two `Animation` objects. You just have to put in the raw resource IDs in the function call, like `R.anim.fade_in`.

Comment: yeah i knw dat. but that is not my question :) I wanted to knw is there any other methods or any alternative way to sumbmit animation variable as parameter.

Comment: You can't submit an `Animation` object between two activities, and more importantly - you *really* don't need to. `Animation` objects itself belongs to the current activity, and therefore the method takes raw resources as parameters. You can simply achieve the same goal using the resource IDs so there's really no reason for bothering with `Animation` objects.